# RF one-shot circuit capable of producing 5-ns pulse

Tags: rf, one-shot

I am looking for a one-shot circuit capable of producing a 5-ns output pulse with short switching time. I saw this one (http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74LV123.pdf) in a previous question, however the switching time is much too long. We ideally want to run our circuit at 100 MHz, so a rise and fall rate of 50 ns/V is much too slow. I did find one from Dallas semiconductor that would work, however it has been discontinued by maxim integrated and there is no replacement product.

I need something that will produce a 5-ns pulse when triggered in order to switch a bipolar transistor.

Thanks!

Comment: Try [74LVC1G123](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g123.pdf). Spec'ed for pulse widths down to 2.5 ns and retrigger times down to 4.5 V, depending on supply voltage.

Answer (score 1):

You could try delaying one input to a [single-gate CMOS exclusive OR](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74LVC1G86.pdf) with an RC network such as 250 ohms/20pF. Drive the input & R with a fast single gate buffer.

You will get a pulse on each edge of the input waveform.

Also, you might want to consider using about 1 meter of coaxial cable as a delay line.

Comment: +1 I have used the coax approach.It outperformed the exclusive OR.